# Group by a column then filtered out the earliest date rows into a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like below:

```
product_id        date         status
    1          2018-09-11        G
    1          2016-01-11        B
    1          2018-02-11        P
    2          2019-06-12        P
    2          2020-10-11        P
    3          2019-07-21        G
    3          2016-09-11        B
    3          2018-12-15        B
    3          2020-11-07        P
    :
    :
    n          2020-11-11        G
```

Since I have duplicate product_id, I am thinking to group by the product id and only filter out the earliest date of the corresponding product_id, but my date column is not a datetime object, so I need to convert it to datetime first or I do not have to if there's other way to do it. The output dataframe should look like below:

```
product_id        date         status
    1          2016-01-11        B
    2          2019-06-12        P
    3          2016-09-11        B
    :
    :
    n          2020-11-11        G
```

I am wondering are there any better or faster ways to achieve my goal other than using group by or maybe drop duplicate?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html) for index of minimal datetime, what is earliest and select values by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df = df.loc[df.groupby('product_id')['date'].idxmin()]
print (df)
   product_id       date status
1           1 2016-01-11      B
3           2 2019-06-12      P
6           3 2016-09-11      B
```

**Detail**: `idxmin` return indices by `product_id` with minimal date:

```
print (df.groupby('product_id')['date'].idxmin())
product_id
1    1
2    3
3    6
Name: date, dtype: int64
```

Or use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df = df.sort_values(['product_id','date']).drop_duplicates('product_id')
print (df)
   product_id       date status
1           1 2016-01-11      B
3           2 2019-06-12      P
6           3 2016-09-11      B
```

Comment: It works, thank you so much! And if you do not mind me asking, would you mind explain what is idxmin and how it works coz I am not very familiar with it

Comment: @CodingStark `idxmin` & `idxmax` is pandas' take on argmax https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arg_max

Comment: @CodingStark - I add some details to answer to see how working `idxmin` here by example data.

Comment: @jezrael Thank you so much! Glad that I am learning new things!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your dates are in YYYY-MM-DD order, the [`ISO-8601`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) definition. So you can simply sort on it:

```
print (df.sort_values("date").drop_duplicates("product_id").sort_index())

   product_id        date status
1           1  2016-01-11      B
3           2  2019-06-12      P
6           3  2016-09-11      B
```

Comment: I I think because performance always is best convert dates to datetimes.